# reinterpret_cast - the same pointer may have multiple integer representations

Tags: c++, c++11

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

> A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size and back to the same pointer type is guaranteed to have its original value, otherwise the resulting pointer cannot be dereferenced safely ***(the round-trip conversion in the opposite direction is not guaranteed; the same pointer may have multiple integer representations)***

What does the statement in bold mean?

Comment: The passage is about the cast chain `pointer` -> `integer` -> `pointer`. I believe the bold section means you can't do `integer` -> `pointer` -> `integer`.

Answer (score 2):

The statement means that this is guaranteed:

```
int a = 0;
int *p1 = &a;
int *p2 = reinterpret_cast<int *>(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p1));
assert(p1 == p2); // OK
```

... but this is not:

```
std::uintptr_t a = 0;
int *b = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(reinterpret_cast<int *>(a));
assert(a == b); // Not necessarily true!
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that for some pointer type P and integer type I of sufficient size, the following holds:

```
P p = ...;
static_assert( p == reinterpret_cast<P>(reinterpret_cast<I>(p) );
```

But not necessarily this:

```
I i = ...;
static_assert( i == reinterpret_cast<I>(reinterpret_cast<P>(i) );
```